# Object-oriented non-linear solving in python

Tags: python, nonlinear-equations, nonlinear-programming, openmodelica

I'd like to build a system in Python, consisting of (broadly speaking) objects which are internally described with (not necessarily just linear) equations, that I can connect with each other - similar to what can be done in OpenModelica. Is there anything like this already available or do I have to use OpenModelica for this?

For now, a steady-state solution is just fine. That's also why I think that OpenModelica would be overkill.